# Can we return a function in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a program containing three functions: `main()`, `returnFunction()` and `functionToBeReturned()`. `main()` has to call `returnFunction()`. Can we use `functionToBeReturned()` as a return value of `returnFunction()`?

```
int functionToBeReturned()
{
    // some code here....
    return value;
}

int returnFunction()
{
    // some code here....
    return functionToBeReturned();
}

int main()
{
    returnFunction();
}
```

Is that okay...

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you *try it* ?

Comment: Currently, `returnFunction` returns the same thing as `functionToBeReturned`, ie. `value` (and to get `value`, `returnFunction` calls `functionToBeReturned`). If you want to return `functionToBeReturned` so that it can be called in main, that´s different (but possible too)

Comment: @-deviantfan Suppose I declare functionToBeReturned() as a boolean return type function. Now functionToBeReturned() is passing a boolean value. returnFunction() remains of int type. What's then?

Comment: @user5117637 Then `returnFunction` calls `functionToBeReturned` to get a `bool` which is then automatically converted to `int` (it´s a bigger type etc. no problem here), and then it´s returned. A boolean `true` will be 1, a `false` 0. About returning the function itself, if that is what you want, see brenns answer below.

Comment: if your signatures are all the same it is easy with function pointers. if not, you can use `closures` with C++11 `std::function` or `boost::function`. otherwise you also have libsignals++

Comment: It may be useful to consider exactly in what order you want things to be called. Can you amend the example with `std::cout << "In function ..."` and the expected output?

Comment: Very close to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31387238/841108) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31387444/841108)

Comment: Is returning "a function" what you actually want to do or is the question about the function call in the return statement?

Comment: It's about using a function call as a return statement.

Comment: @whozcraig Yes...I tried it. Results were same as told by deviantfan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you can have and return function pointers; they basically point to machine code that you can call. You might have some library functions able to "create" functions (e.g. dynamically generate or load some machine code) and give a pointer to the newly created code (`dlsym`, JIT libraries, ....)
But, in pure standard C99 or C11 or C++11, there is no way to *create* raw plain functions (at the machine code level) at runtime. In a program restricted to *standard* C++ or C, the set of functions is fixed (and is the set of values all pointer functions can get, in addition of the `NULL` pointer). Since C is lacking proper closures, many C frameworks (e.g. [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or its Glib, [libevent](http://libevent.org/), ....) deal with [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), implemented by a *convention* mixing function pointer and client data (for example, read the [GTK tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html), see [g_signal_connect](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect), ...)

In C++ (C++11 or newer), you can also have [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), anonymous functions (i.e. lambda-s), and `std::function`; for example

```
 std::function<int(int)> translation(int delta) {
    return [delta](int x) { return x + delta; };
 }
```

In the returned closure (which semantically behaves almost as a function, since you can call and apply it), the `delta` is a closed value.

<sup>Closures are an extremely important and difficult concept, related to [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). Don't be surprised to need weeks to understand it. See also [Scheme](http://www.schemers.org/), [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html), [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)....</sup>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387444/841108) to a quite similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31387238/841108) gives much more details.

At the machine level, a C or C++ function pointer is very often some address pointing into the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment), but a C++ closure is some internal object (of some "anonymous" class, internal to your compiler implementation) mixing code pointers and closed values or references.

Learning some functional programming language like Ocaml or Scheme or Clojure or Haskell or Common Lisp will improve your thinking (even when coding in C or C++).

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  Function pointers are part of C and C++.  Using function pointers, you can return functions from other functions, and store them in classes, etc.  [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) is an article about them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int functionToBeReturned() {
    cout << "hello!" << endl;
}
int (*returnFunction())() {
    // Observe how the parentheses around returnFunction distinguish a function
    // returning a function pointer from a normal function.
    return functionToBeReturned;
}
int main() {
    int (*function)();
    function = returnFunction();
    function();
}
```

In this program, `returnFunction` is a function that takes nothing and returns a function that takes nothing and returns an int.  Declarations involving function pointers are really ugly in C and C++!  You might consider doing this for clarity:

```
typedef int (*returns_int_t)();
```

This defines the name `returns_int_t` for a pointer to a function, which takes nothing and returns an int.  Then, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*returns_int_t)();

int functionToBeReturned() {
    cout << "hello!" << endl;
}
returns_int_t returnFunction() {
    return functionToBeReturned;
}
int main() {
    returns_int_t function = returnFunction();
    function();
}
```

Which does the exact same thing.

Comment: Returning a function pointer isn't the same thing as returning the function itself (which isn't legal in C++). In practice, it's far more useful to use function objects (`std::function`, `std::bind`, lambdas) than it is to use function pointers.

Comment: Very good point!  I've been using much more C than C++ lately, so I'm used to the reduced feature set.